# The field must be an accumulator object. (The field is date string.)

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

**I am trying to group by the date string and count how many data on each date.**

First I transfer the ISOdate to date string:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
                yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$file_date" } }
        }
    },
])
```

The result:

[image: nter image description here]

So far so good until I do this:

```
db.closing_nassau.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
                yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$detail.file_date" } }
        }
    },
    { $group: { date: "$yearMonthDay", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
])
```

It keeps showing:

> "message" : "The field 'date' must be an accumulator object"

I think this should work. I first transfer the ISOdate to date string. And I group by date string and count each date. I have tried removing `count: { $sum: 1 }` and it still shows the same error so the problem is on the group by.

Feel free to ask further informations in order to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `_id` to specify a grouping key:

```
db.closing_nassau.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
                yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$detail.file_date" } }
        }
    },
    { $group: { _id: "$yearMonthDay", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
])
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#pipe._S_group)

Comment: You are God. You save my day! Thank you so much! Will definitely read the link!